# how to get url of request parameters came from

Tags: jsp, servlets, httprequest

> I have 2 different form submit pages  eg: **reg1.jsp and reg2.jsp.**
>   
>  After request submitted from the pages in servlet page where i
>   get request parameters of the form.  
> Here i want to fetch the url
>   or page name  from where the request parameter submitted. is there any
>   method? i tried `request.getRequestURI();` this gives me servlet uri.
>   but i want to get uri of request origin page name where requested
>   submitted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to achieve this. 
 we need to add page name as parameter in hidden field if it is html or if  jsp means we can add pagename in session using `session.setAttribute("pagename","reg1.jsp");`

Answer (score 0):

```
request.getRequestURL()
```

This will allows you to identify the file path.

```
request.getContextPath()
```

This will allows you to identify the Context path.

Comment: this will show current page file path and context path.. not actual path from request came.